# Android runOnUiThread not displaying

Tags: android, android-runonuithread

So I have a problem with an Android App I'm giving maintenance they have a callBack on the app that is trigger when something happens, and there is a runOnUiThread. However it seems not to be working but. When I minimize the app and I resume it... It shows the changes. (I have already tried the invalidate and postInvalidate... The only command that seems to work it's recreate, but it shows a black screen and the reloads the app, I don't want that to happen)

```
private ServiceCallback<ProductIntoItem> getInfoCallback = new ServiceCallback<ProductIntoItem>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final ProductIntoItem productIntoItem) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Tag tag = new Tag("", epcReadings.get(0));
                tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("info item"));
                tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("info sku"));
                tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(InfoProductActivity.this);
                infoItemFragment = InfoItemFragment.newInstance(productIntoItem, location, tag.getSku());
                infoSkuFragment = InfoSkuFragment.newInstance(productIntoItem, location, tag.getSku());
                initWithFragment(R.id.container_tabs_info, infoItemFragment);

                recreate();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(NetworkException e) {
    }
};
```

**Edit**

The callback is called from this section of the code: (The onTagRead method is native from a device that's bluetooth connected. This is all inside the Running Activity class)

```
@Override
public void onTagRead(String epc) {

    if (epc != null) {
        rfIdManager.stopTagReading();
        epcReadings.add(epc);
    }
    if (epcReadings.size() >= 1 && epcReadings.size() < 2 && isNetworkConnectionAvailable()) {
        network.getInfoItem(epcReadings.get(0), getInfoCallback);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that your runnable does get called?

Comment: There is this code section, this override comes from a bluetooth device.  `@Override
    public void onTagRead(String epc) {
        if (epc != null) {
            rfIdManager.stopTagReading();
            epcReadings.add(epc);
        }
        if (epcReadings.size() >= 1 && epcReadings.size() < 2 && isNetworkConnectionAvailable()) {
            network.getInfoItem(epcReadings.get(0), getInfoCallback);
        }
    }`